# Getting/setting Track Changes setting property value trough DTE in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, envdte, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio extension that gets the value and then sets a value to the 
Text Editor -> General -> Track Changes setting in the Options dialog.

A code that was working fine with Visual Studio 2012-2017:

```
DTE vsEnvironment = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
Property trackChangesProperty = vsEnvironment.Properties["TextEditor", "General"].Item("TrackChanges");
```

is throwing a `COMException` with the following message:  *"Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))"* at `EnvDTE._DTE.get_Properties(String Category, String Page)` in Visual Studio 2019.

Apparently the setting is moved, so I, trying to get the new location, exported the settings to file in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019, and compared the results:

- Visual Studio 2017:

  > ```
  > <ToolsOptionsCategory name="TextEditor" RegisteredName="TextEditor">
  > <ToolsOptionsSubCategory name="General" RegisteredName="General" PackageName="Text Management Package">
  >     <PropertyValue name="TrackChanges">true</PropertyValue>
  > </ToolsOptionsSubCategory>
  > ```
- Visual Studio 2019:

  > ```
  > <Category name="Text Editor_General" Category="{c178af61-531a-46f0-bd57-102d9e42c711}" Package="{e269b994-ef71-4ce0-8bcd-581c217372e8}" RegisteredName="Text Editor_General" PackageName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage">
  > <PropertyValue name="TrackChanges">true</PropertyValue>
  > ```

I am still not sure how to use the information, as the indexer of the `DTE.Properties` accepts two parameters: `Category` and `Page`. I already tried the following:

```
        vsEnvironment.Properties["TextEditor", null].Item("TrackChanges");
        vsEnvironment.Properties["TextEditor", string.Empty].Item("TrackChanges");
        vsEnvironment.Properties["Text Editor_General", null].Item("TrackChanges");
        vsEnvironment.Properties["Text Editor_General", string.Empty].Item("TrackChanges");
```

but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft staff [clarified](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/547725/view.html) that any of the following approaches can be used:

- Use `IVsTextManager3.SetUserPreferences3()`. Available in older versions of Visual Studio as well (I tested with Visual Studio 2012 - 2019), but pretty ugly API:

  ```
  IVsTextManager3 textManager = this.GetService(typeof(VsTextManagerClass)) as IVsTextManager3;

  VIEWPREFERENCES3[] viewPreferences3Array = new VIEWPREFERENCES3[1];
  FONTCOLORPREFERENCES2[] fontColorPreferences2Array = new FONTCOLORPREFERENCES2[1];
  FRAMEPREFERENCES2[] framePreferences2Array = new FRAMEPREFERENCES2[1];
  LANGPREFERENCES2[] langPreferences2Array = new LANGPREFERENCES2[1];

  textManager.GetUserPreferences3(viewPreferences3Array, framePreferences2Array, langPreferences2Array, fontColorPreferences2Array);

  VIEWPREFERENCES3 viewPreferences3 = viewPreferences3Array[0];
  viewPreferences3.fTrackChanges = 0;
  textManager.SetUserPreferences3(new VIEWPREFERENCES3[] { viewPreferences3 }, framePreferences2Array, langPreferences2Array, fontColorPreferences2Array);
  ```
- Use `IEditorOptionsFactoryService` MEF service. This API is added in Visual Studio 2019 and later:

  ```
  <IEditorOptionsFactoryService>.GlobalOptions.GetOptionValue<bool>(DefaultTextViewHostOptions.ChangeTrackingId);
  <IEditorOptionsFactoryService>.GlobalOptions.SetOptionValue<bool>(DefaultTextViewHostOptions.ChangeTrackingId, <true/false>);
  ```